# Site Breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a site and want to add breadcrumbs with border radius. I'm having trouble trying to make it look like breadcrumbs with 2nd and 3rd child z index.
What i want to achieve is the 2nd and 3rd child under the previous list.
[image]

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1cnh7bz7/1/

this is my code

```
.uk-breadcrumb > li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.uk-breadcrumb > li,
.uk-breadcrumb > li > a,
.uk-breadcrumb > li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.uk-breadcrumb .uk-active {
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  z-index: 2;
}
<div class="bh-breadcrumbs">
<ul class="uk-breadcrumb uk-hidden-small">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Culture">Culture</a></li>
    <li class="uk-active"><span>arts</span></li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

any help appriciated

Comment: Please, could you make it clearer on what is the problem you are facing? The fiddle looks about right to me...

Comment: updated the question and added the image of what i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a little hack on the `z-index` to make it work. First of all, you were playing with `z-index` without using a position value, so it had no effect. See the lines `.uk-breadcrumb > li + li` it targets a element `li` next to another `li` and used multiple of these to determine if it is the first, second or third and then applied the correct z-index.

I've started the `z-index` at 10 but could have started at any number, but starting higher than needed makes it easier to just add a level if we wanted 4 levels instead of three. I am sure the community can find a better way to do it by nexting instead, but this will work well enough...

```css
.uk-breadcrumb > li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.uk-breadcrumb > li {
  z-index: 10;
}
.uk-breadcrumb > li + li {
  z-index: 9;
}
.uk-breadcrumb > li + li+ li {
  z-index: 8;
}
.uk-breadcrumb > li,
.uk-breadcrumb > li > a,
.uk-breadcrumb > li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.uk-breadcrumb .uk-active {
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="bh-breadcrumbs">
  <ul class="uk-breadcrumb uk-hidden-small">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Culture">Culture</a>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-active"><span>arts</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```